# CountDownTimer strange behaviour

Tags: android, countdowntimer

Hello everybody and thanks in advance!,

I've got a CountDownTimer that I want to make a pause while I show an increasing count from 1 to a given number, with an interval. The thing is that, with the code below, the counter sometimes get to 29 but sometimes just 28 and I don't know why.

Can anybody help me?.

```
    public void CountDown(View v)
{
    int FinishNumber = 30;

    final CountDownTimer CountDown = new CountDownTimer(FinishNumber * 100, 100)
    {
        int NumberToShow = 1;

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            CopyrightTV.setText(String.valueOf(NumberToShow++));
        }

        public void onFinish()
        {
            CopyrightTV.setText(String.valueOf(NumberToShow));
            this.cancel();
        }
    }
            .start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not such a strange behaviour - take into consideration that the first onTick(long millisUntilFinished) only invoked after 100ms (that is the interval you've set), and not when you start the CountDownTimer.

Secondly CountDownTimer is not a 100% precise timer, so you can expect this "strange behaviour".

**EDIT**

If the accuracy is not extremely important, you could try increasing the CountDownTimer by a few hundreds ms, something like this:

```
  public void CountDown(final TextView v)
  {
    final int FinishNumber = 30;

    final CountDownTimer CountDown = new CountDownTimer((FinishNumber + 4)  * 100, 100)
    {
        int NumberToShow = 1;

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            if (NumberToShow < FinishNumber)
                v.setText(String.valueOf(NumberToShow++));
        }

        public void onFinish()
        {
            if (NumberToShow < FinishNumber)
                v.setText(String.valueOf(NumberToShow));
        }
    }
        .start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Udi Idan, so how would you do what I want to do? Wich method, function, etc, would you use?